# qrcode value insertion into mysql database using php code

Tags: php, sql

I created a sql database on my localhost machine later on i'd like to connect it to an online sql server for now i'd like to read the qr code using php code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect(“localhost“,”root“,”root“) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(“omi“) or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query(“insert into $_GET[table] values ($_GET[id])”)
or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

which must take the input via a url localhost.com/get.php?table=id,id=1234
but there is an error saying parsing error on line 4,
for reading via QRcode i will insert the server address in the QRcode along with the php values and read it via a barcode reader and push the code to insertion.
how do i get the code working ??

Comment: You're using MS Word to code? See those curly quotes `“ ”` replace them with regular quotes `"` if that is your actual code.

Comment: so should it be like: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("omi") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("insert into $_GET[table] values ($_GET[id])")
or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: What's the error?  There are a lot of things that could be going wrong here.  One thing that you might want to look at is the URL itself.  

`localhost.com/get.php?table=id,id=1234` doesn't have an "ID" field that would be accessable via $_GET[id].  You might need to change the URL to `localhost.com/get.php?table=id&id=1234` (replace the , with an &)

Comment: also I think you have to specify the collumn name you want insert $_get['id'] into, like this: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(col2*2,15); `

Comment: ok ill change it to & richard87 i think it should work i tried the query.

Comment: *"so should it be like..."* - Sure, sort of. However, doing this leaves you open to a massive [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Comment: on doing the changes Table 'omi.id' doesn't exist error occurs even though i have executed the query create table id(id int primary key);

Comment: ok so it becomes highly insecure

Comment: `get.php?table=TABLE_NAME&id=1234`

Comment: it worked for local host but when im trying to connect to a remote server say 123.12.123.76:3306 how do i run it using the url?? so i can connect the php code with it??